# Dynamics 365 Workflow to set a field to "Yes" on all records

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to set a custom two-options field to "Yes" to trigger a plugin that I wrote. Looking through some searches and documentation, it seems like this should be possible using a Workflow, however I'm not quite getting it to work as I thought it would. I want to be able to just run the Workflow once, and have all of the records have that one field update.

Currently:
I added an "Update Record" step set to the primary entity that has the field to change.
Clicked on "Set Properties"
Selected "Yes" for the desired field.
Chose the "Add" button when the entity and field dropdowns auto populated.
Lastly selected the "Default Value: Yes" radio option and hit ok.

"{FieldName(EntityName);Yes}" was then generated and put on the form, I saved and activated the Workflow, however nothing seems to have happened.

I feel like I am either not understanding how the Workflow is supposed to work or I am missing a step, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an On-Demand workflow and select all the records for which you want to update the field through advance find and run the workflow. For new records you can trigger the workflow on record creation.

Answer (score 1):

Once activated, a workflow does not just run for all records in the system. It must be applied to each record separately by either:

- creating a record
- modifying a record
- deleting a record
- manually applying the workflow to a record